# Python: Unit testing for date changes

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing

I was doing the following for a Django form definition (embarrassing, yes):

```
class DealAdvancedSearchForm(forms.Form):
    weekday_choices = [
        ['monday', 'Monday'],
        ['tuesday', 'Tuesday'],
        ['wednesday', 'Wednesday'],
        ['thursday', 'Thursday'],
        ['friday', 'Friday'],
        ['saturday', 'Saturday'],
        ['sunday', 'Sunday'],
    ]
    weekday_index = date.today().weekday()
    weekday_choices[weekday_index][1] += ' (Today)' 
    weekday_choices[weekday_index+1][1] += ' (Tomorrow)'
    weekday = forms.ChoiceField(label='Day of the week', choices=weekday_choices, required=False)
```

As you probably guessed by now, this works fine as long as `date.today()` does not change. All my tests passed. However, once the date changes, it is incorrectly keeping initial date's choice marked as today.

I have since figured out how dumb this was and have moved the code into the `__init__` method.

Now I want to write a test for it. Does anyone know how would I test that the correct weekday is marked as `(Today)` when the date changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index out of bounds error:

```
Watch out for [weekday_index+1] for 'sunday', 
use [(weekday_index+1)%7] to wrap down to 0.
```

Extract the choices into a method to make it easy to test. If the method only contains python and no django, it will be easier to test and thus easier to understand.  I also agree that you should create an **__*init*__**, *today* can change at the the end of today and needs to vary with that.

```
def weekday_choices(self, todays_index):
    ...
    return choices_list
```

EDIT:

- Currently your code runs exactly once.
- Move the logic to operate on an instance instead of at the class level.
- Use a library like [MiniMock](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/MiniMock/1.2.5) to mock responses from date.today().weekday().

  - date.today() will need to return a mock that will use `returns_iter`.
- Instanciate 2 forms and assert that their choices lists are as expected.

  - One for today's date, one for tomorrow.
- You can mock for the modulo test too.

Comment: +1 for the modulus suggestion. However, what I want is to test what will happen if the date changes.

Comment: @NimmyLebby, I added some info on MiniMock. A very useful tool to help with testing.

Comment: I cannot +1 again but I'm going to dive into this tomorrow night. Sounds like solid suggestions. Thanks!